# Nested for loop and alternate map method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm a beginner in javascript, so bear with me if this question is too simple. I'm trying to simplify this function

```
var calculateTotal =function(nodeData){

    var totalSelectedUnit0 = 0;
    var totalSelectedUnit1 = 0;
    var totalSelectedUnit2 = 0;

    for(x=$scope.selectFrom; x<$scope.selectTo; x++){
        totalSelectedUnit0 += nodeData.items[0].usage.categories[x].current;
        totalSelectedUnit1 += nodeData.items[1].usage.categories[x].current;
        totalSelectedUnit2 += nodeData.items[2].usage.categories[x].current;
    }
    console.log(totalSelectedUnit0);
    console.log(totalSelectedUnit1);
    console.log(totalSelectedUnit2);

};

calculateTotal(node);
```

And this is how I attempted to refactor the code

```
var calculateTotal =function(nodeData){
    var totalSelectedUnit=[];
    for(i=0; i<nodeData.items.length; i++){
        for(x=$scope.selectFrom; x<$scope.selectTo; x++){
            totalSelectedUnit[i] += nodeData.items[i].usage.categories[x].current;
        }
    }
    console.log(totalSelectedUnit);
};
```

There are couple of things I'm trying to achieve here. The calculation should ignore `null` or `Nan` values. Also I would like to use the `map` and `reduce` to achieve this calculation.

Comment: Your function seems ok at first glimpse. Is it working as expected? what console.log(totalSelectedUnit); gives? is there any error under particular circumstances?

Comment: If you want to ignore `null` or `NaN` values in `x += y` you can say `x += y || 0` (noting that [JavaScript's logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) don't work quite the same way as in most other languages). You'd also need `totalSelectedUnit[i] = 0` before the inner `for` loop. I don't think `.map()` makes much sense here.

Comment: Regarding your error, do all `nodeData.items` array entries have a `usage` property?

Comment: Sorry small mistake with code..now it is outputting `-` , just a hyphen, Assuming we that some items do not have usage property, how can we skip those and calculate rest?

Comment: Be really careful when declaring variables in your `for` statements.

For example:

`for(i=0;...`

Is creating a GLOBAL variables on the window object called `i`. This WILL cause you pain in the future. Always use the `var` keyword when declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I could see is the result array is not initialized, so the result will be `NaN` as you are adding an `undefined` value to a number.

```js
var calculateTotal = function(nodeData) {
  var totalSelectedUnit = nodeData.items.map(function(item) { //create a result value for each item in the items array
    return item.usage.categories.slice($scope.selectFrom, $scope.selectTo).reduce(function(v1, v2) { //sum up values between the from and to index
      return v1 + (v2 || 0); //ignore the falsy values
    }, 0);
  })

  console.log(totalSelectedUnit);
};

var $scope = {
  selectFrom: 0,
  selectTo: 4
};

var nodeData = {
  items: [{
    usage: {
      categories: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
    }
  }, {
    usage: {
      categories: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10]
    }
  }, {
    usage: {
      categories: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 20]
    }
  }]
};

calculateTotal(nodeData);
```

Comment: The code seems fine, but did you missed the `current` part? `categories[x].current`

Comment: @anoopchandran You could just add that, creating a dummy data with that structure is a bit difficult that is why I omitted that

Comment: You are right, i fixed this by initialising my result array. `var totalSelectedUnit=[];
        for(i=0; i<nodeData.items.length; i++){
            totalSelectedUnit[i] = 0;
        }`